# How to get query list that does not exist in another model in Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm

I have three table:

**Table1**

```py
class Table1(models.Model):
    field1 = model.CharField(...)
    field2 = model.CharField(...)
```

**Table2**

```py
class Table2(models.Model):
    field1 = model.CharField(...)
    field2 = model.CharField(...)
```

**Table3**

```py
class Table3(models.Model):
    table1 = model.ForeignKey(Table1)
    table2 = model.ForeignKey(Table2)
```

I want to get all **Table1** data that does not exists in **Table3** with a which also includes **Table2**.

For Example:
In **Table1** I have three rows:
rows1, rows2, rows3

In **Table2** I have One rows:
r1

In **Table3** I have One rows:
table1 = rows1
table2 = r1

I want to get rows2 and rows3 from **Table1** when I am searching against **Table2**s r1 in **Table3**

I can get my expected result using this code:

```py
table3 = Table3.objects.filter(table2=Table2.objects.get(id=1)).values_list('table1')
queryset = Table1.objects.filter(~Q(id__in=table3 ))
```

My Question now is there any better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: What is `r1` here?

Comment: `r1` is id from `Table2` I am editing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with [**`.exclude(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#exclude):

```
Table1.objects.exclude(table3__table2_id=1)
```